# Convert HTML to Word and embed file hyperlinks as attachments

Tags: html, vba, ms-office, ms-word

I have some HTML files that I'm opening with Word and saving as docx files. I have some macros I run to break the links on the graphics so that they get embedded in the doc file, but I haven't figured out any way to convert the file hyperlinks into embedded attachments.

When I open the htm files in word, it looks like this:

```
{HYPERLINK "C:\\xxxx\\test.zip \o "test.zip"}
```

The actual html code when opened in Notepad looks basically like this

```
<a href="C:\xxxx\test.zip" title="test.zip"><img src="C:\xxxx\0000002.gif" style="border-width: 0" /><span style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 9pt; color: #000000">test.zip</span></a>
```

With the .gif being a little icon that represents zip files.

Ideally I want the end docx file to look like I had just manually dragged in a file and attached it within the body of the document.

Comment: This is done manually from Insert File, no? Have you tried using the macro recorder to get an example of this? (Sometimes the macro recorder in Word is useless...)

Comment: Looks like it uses Selection.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject ClassType:="CompressedFolder" but I'm not sure how I could convert my existing hyperlinks to something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I think probably the best way would be to parse the HTM file as plain text, rather than opening it in word, but I don't have time to do that at the moment. This might work, using the windows default location for the ZIP icon.

```
Sub Macro2()

'Assume example structure like:
'"{HYPERLINK "C:\\xxxx\\test.zip \o "test.zip"}"

Dim htmLink As String
Dim fileName As String
Dim iconLabel As String

Dim v As Variant


'## Do you want to display the file icon?
showIcon = True

'## the htm "link" you need to change:
htmLink = "{HYPERLINK ""c:\\users\\david_zemens\\desktop\\1-8 test.zip \o ""1.8 test.zip""}"


'## reformat the link:
    ' first split it by space (assumes no spaces in the filename...
    v = Split(htmLink, """")

    'v(1) is the location of the file;
    ' you can verify in the Locals window
    fileName = Replace(v(1), Chr(34), vbNullString)
    fileName = Replace(fileName, "\\", "\")
    fileName = Replace(fileName, " \o", vbNullString)
    fileName = Trim(fileName)

    'v(2) is the filename:
    iconLabel = v(2)

'## Add to your document
' modify "Selection" to refer to any Word.Range, I think
    Selection.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject ClassType:="Package", fileName:= _
        fileName, LinkToFile:=False, _
        DisplayAsIcon:=True, IconFileName:="C:\Windows\system32\packager.dll", _
        IconIndex:=0, iconLabel:=iconLabel


End Sub
```